# caching frameworks for .net 4.5.1 [.net core (dnx)]

Tags: caching, redis, .net-core

We are trying to build an application in asp.net 5 which is built on .net core.
What are the in-memory caching options available to us. We tried creating a POC using Redis (open source caching server), but it was unsuccessful as we could not get it to work with .net core. 
What are the different options we can consider?
We want the application to be platform independent and hence we have selected asp.net 5.
My question may seem noobish ;) but even we have not invested sufficient time in understanding the new asp.net 5 due to a very strict deadline.
Any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Which Redis client have you used? [StackExchange.Redis has DNXCore 5.0 support](https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/1.1.572-alpha)

Comment: The pre-release version of StackExchange.Redis has DNXCore 5.0 support. It seems a little buggy for advanced options like LUA scripting, But, we have selected the StackExchange.Redis client and have proceeded with the development. The journey has been smooth with a couple of hiccups but we are sure the Client will definitely stabilize soon.